# Quicken Code to get Past Godaddy Server Timeout

Tags: php, database, connection-timeout, rets, phrets

I have an issue where I need to data from a RETS server and populate it on the database, I was able to get all but two tables to properly automate this data in, but I'm having issues with the last (and biggest) two. After looking at it, the issue is timeout with the server, it cannot finish in time for the database to populate.

I am working off of a godaddy server and already have the maximum time I can set for the program to run, the only thing I can do now is figure out a way to speed up my code so it finishes in time, and would like some help figuring that out.

The code (posted below) was modified to fit my needs from here: https://github.com/coreyrowell/retshelper/blob/master/rets_helper.php

While it works well and I was able to get it working, I haven't been able to figure out the best way to speed it up. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

```
<?php
/*
.---------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|  Software: RETSHELPER - PHP Class to interface RETS with Database         |
|   Version: 1.0                                                            |
|   Contact: corey@coreyrowell.com                                          |
|      Info: None                                                           |
|   Support: corey@coreyrowell.com                                          |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
|    Author: Corey Rowell - corey@coreyrowell.com                           |
| Copyright (c) 2013, Corey Rowell. All Rights Reserved.                    |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
|   License: This content is released under the                             |
|                   (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) MIT License.       |                                    |
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------'
*/
/*
.---------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|   This software requires the use of the PHPRETS library                   |
|   http://troda.com/projects/phrets/                                       |
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------'
*/
define("BASE_PATH",dirname(__FILE__)."/");

ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',0);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout',0);

class RETSHELPER
{
// Defaults
private $rets, $auth, $config, $database, $mysqli, $data, $log, $scriptstart, $scriptend,
$previous_start_time, $current_start_time, $updates_log, $active_ListingRids = array();
public function __construct()
{
// Require PHRETS library
require_once("phrets.php");
// Start rets connection
$this->rets = new phRETS;
$this->scriptstart = date("m-d-y_h-i-s", time());
    // RETS Server Info
    $this->auth['url']          = 'redacted';//MLS_URL;//MLS_URL;
    $this->auth['username']     = 'redacted';        //MLS_USERNAME;
    $this->auth['password']     = 'redacted';     //MLS_PASS;
    $this->auth['retsversion']  = '';           //USER Agent Version
    $this->auth['useragent']    = '';           //USER Agent
    // RETS Options
    $this->config['property_classes']   = array("A");//,"B","C","D","E","F");
    $this->config['KeyField']           = "LIST_1";
    $this->config['offset_support']     = TRUE; // Enable if RETS server supports 'offset'
    $this->config['useragent_support']  = FALSE;
    $this->config['images_path']        = BASE_PATH."listing_photos/";
    $this->config['logs_path']          = BASE_PATH."logs/";
    $this->config['start_times_path']   = BASE_PATH."logs/";
    $this->config['previous_start_time'] = $this->get_previous_start_time();
    $this->config['create_tables']      = FALSE; // Create tables for classes (terminates program)
    // Log to screen?
    $this->config['to_screen']          = TRUE;
    // Database Config
    $this->database['host']     = 'redacted';  //DB_SERVER;
    $this->database['username'] = 'redacted';       //DB_USER;
    $this->database['password'] = 'redacted';           //DB_PASS;
    $this->database['database'] = 'redacted';       //DB_NAME;
    $this->config_init();
    // Load the run function
    $this->run();
}
private function config_init()
{
    // Set offset support based on config
    if($this->config['offset_support'])
    {
        $this->rets->SetParam("offset_support", true);
    } else {
        $this->rets->SetParam("offset_support", false);
    }
    if($this->config['useragent_support'])
    {
        $this->rets->AddHeader("RETS-Version", $this->auth['retsversion']);
        $this->rets->AddHeader("User-Agent", $this->auth['useragent']);
    }
}
public function run()
{
    // Start Logging
    $this->logging_start();
    // RETS Connection
    $this->connect();
    // Connect to Database
    $this->database_connect();
    if($this->config['create_tables'])
    {
        $this->log_data("Creating database tables, program will exit after finishing.");
        foreach ($this->config['property_classes'] as $class)
        {
            $this->log_data("Creating table for: " . $class);
            $this->create_table_for_property_class($class);
        }
        $this->log_data("Exiting program.");
        return;
    }
    // Get Properties (and images)
    $this->get_properties_by_class();
    // Close RETS Connection
    $this->disconnect();
    // Delete inactive listings
    $this->database_delete_records();
    // Insert new listings
    $this->database_insert_records();
    // Disconnect from Database
    $this->database_disconnect();
    // End Logging
    $this->logging_end();
    // Time for next scheduled update
    $this->set_previous_start_time();
}
private function connect()
{
    $this->log_data("Connecting to RETS...");
    // Connect to RETS
    $connect = $this->rets->Connect($this->auth['url'], $this->auth['username'], $this->auth['password']);
    if($connect)
    {
        $this->log_data("Successfully connected to RETS.");
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $error = $this->rets->Error();
        if($error['text'])
        {
            $error = $error['text'];
        } else {
            $error = "No error message returned from RETS. Check RETS debug file.";
        }
        $this->log_error("Failed to connect to RETS.\n".$error);
        die();
    }
}
private function get_properties_by_class()
{
    $this->log_data("Getting Classes...");
    foreach ($this->config['property_classes'] as $class)
    {
        $this->log_data("Getting Class: ".$class);
        // Set
        $fields_order = array();
        $mod_timestamp_field = $this->get_timestamp_field($class);
        $previous_start_time = $this->config['previous_start_time'];
        $search_config = array('Format' => 'COMPACT-DECODED', 'QueryType' => 'DMQL2', 'Limit'=> 1000, 'Offset' => 1, 'Count' => 1);
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
        |                                                                                 |
        | If you're having problems, they probably lie here in the $query and/or $search. |
        |                                                                                 |
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Query
        $query = "({$mod_timestamp_field}=2016-09-16T00:00:00-2016-09-16T01:00:00)";//{$previous_start_time}+)";
        // Run Search
        $search = $this->rets->SearchQuery("Property", $class, $query, $search_config);
        // Get all active listings
        $query_all = "({$mod_timestamp_field}=1980-01-01T00:00:00+)";
        $search_all = $this->rets->SearchQuery("Property", $class, $query_all, array('Format'=>'COMPACT', 'Select'=>$this->config['KeyField']));
        $tmpArray = array();
        while($active_rid = $this->rets->FetchRow($search_all)) {
            array_push($tmpArray, $active_rid[$this->config['KeyField']]);
        }
        $this->active_ListingRids['property_'.strtolower($class)] = $tmpArray;
        $data = array();
       if ($this->rets->NumRows($search) > 0)
        {
            // Get columns
            $fields_order = $this->rets->SearchGetFields($search);
            $this->data['headers'] = $fields_order;
            // Process results
            while ($record = $this->rets->FetchRow($search))
            {
                $this_record = array();
                // Loop it
                foreach ($fields_order as $fo)
                {
                    $this_record[$fo] = $record[$fo];
                }
                $ListingRid = $record[$this->config['KeyField']];
                $data[] = $this_record;
            }
        }
        // Set data
        $this->data['classes'][$class] = $data;
        $this->log_data("Finished Getting Class: ".$class . "\nTotal found: " .$this->rets->TotalRecordsFound());
        // Free RETS Result
        $this->rets->FreeResult($search);
    }
}
private function get_timestamp_field($class)
{
    $class = strtolower($class);
    switch($class)
    {
        case 'a':
            $field = "LIST_87";
            break;              
    }
    return $field;
}
private function disconnect()
{
    $this->log_data("Disconnected from RETS.");
    $this->rets->Disconnect();
}
private function database_connect()
{
    $this->log_data("Connecting to database...");
    $host     = $this->database['host'];
    $username = $this->database['username'];
    $password = $this->database['password'];
    $database = $this->database['database'];
    // Create connection
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
    // Throw error if connection fails
    if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
        $this->log_error("Database Connection Error". $this->mysqli->connect_error);
        die('Connect Error (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
    }
}
private function database_delete_records()
{
    $this->log_data("Updating database...");
    // Loop through each table and update
    foreach($this->config['property_classes'] as $class)
    {
        // Get Tables
        $table = "rets_property_".strtolower($class);
        $activeListings = $this->active_ListingRids['property_'.strtolower($class)];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE {$this->config['KeyField']} NOT IN (".implode(',', $activeListings).");";

        $this->mysqli->query($sql);
        if($this->mysqli->affected_rows > 0)
        {
            $this->log_data("Deleted {$this->mysqli->affected_rows} Listings.");
//      return TRUE;
        } else if($this->mysqli->affected_rows == 0) {
            $this->log_data("Deleted {$this->mysqli->affected_rows} Listings.");
        } else {
            $this->log_data("Deleting database records failed \n\n" . mysqli_error($this->mysqli));
//      return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
private function database_insert_records()
{
    $this->log_data("Inserting records...");
    foreach($this->config['property_classes'] as $class)
    {
        // Get Tables
        $table = "rets_property_".strtolower($class);
        // Get data
        $data_row = $this->data['classes'][$class];
        // Defaults
        $total_rows = 0;
        $total_affected_rows = 0;
        // Loop through data
        foreach($data_row as $drow)
        {
            // Clean data
            // replace empty with NULL
            // and wrap data in quotes
            $columns = array();
            $values = array();
            foreach($drow as $key => $val)
            {
                if($val === '')
                {
                    $val = '""';
                } else {
                    $val = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->mysqli ,$val);
                    $val = "'$val'";
                }
                $columns[] = $key;
                $values[] = $val;
            }
            // Implode data rows with commas
            $values = implode(', ', $values);
            $columns = implode(', ', $columns);
            // Build SQL
            $sql = "REPLACE INTO {$table} ({$columns}) VALUES ({$values})";
            // Do query
            $this->mysqli->query($sql);
            if($this->mysqli->affected_rows > 0)
            {
                $total_affected_rows++;
            } else {
                $this->log_error("Failed to insert the following record: ".$sql . "\n\n" . mysqli_error($this->mysqli));
            }
            $total_rows++;
        }
        $this->log_data("Done inserting data. ".$class."\nTotal Records: ".$total_rows." .\nTotal Inserted: ".$total_affected_rows);
    }
}
private function database_disconnect()
{
    $this->log_data("Database disconnected...");
    // Close connection
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
private function create_table_for_property_class($class)
{
    // gets resource information.  need this for the KeyField
    $rets_resource_info = $this->rets->GetMetadataInfo();
    $resource = "Property";
    // pull field format information for this class
    $rets_metadata = $this->rets->GetMetadata($resource, $class);
    $table_name = "rets_".strtolower($resource)."_".strtolower($class);
    // i.e. rets_property_resi
    $sql = $this->create_table_sql_from_metadata($table_name, $rets_metadata, $rets_resource_info[$resource]['KeyField']);
    $this->mysqli->query($sql);
}
private function create_table_sql_from_metadata($table_name, $rets_metadata, $key_field, $field_prefix = "")
{
    $sql_query = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (\n";
    foreach ($rets_metadata as $field) {
        $field['SystemName'] = "`{$field_prefix}{$field['SystemName']}`";
        $cleaned_comment = addslashes($field['LongName']);
        $sql_make = "{$field['SystemName']} ";
        if ($field['Interpretation'] == "LookupMulti") {
            $sql_make .= "TEXT";
        }
        elseif ($field['Interpretation'] == "Lookup") {
            $sql_make .= "VARCHAR(50)";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Int" || $field['DataType'] == "Small" || $field['DataType'] == "Tiny") {
            $sql_make .= "INT({$field['MaximumLength']})";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Long") {
            $sql_make .= "BIGINT({$field['MaximumLength']})";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "DateTime") {
            $sql_make .= "DATETIME default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' not null";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Character" && $field['MaximumLength'] <= 255) {
            $sql_make .= "VARCHAR({$field['MaximumLength']})";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Character" && $field['MaximumLength'] > 255) {
            $sql_make .= "TEXT";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Decimal") {
            $pre_point = ($field['MaximumLength'] - $field['Precision']);
            $post_point = !empty($field['Precision']) ? $field['Precision'] : 0;
            $sql_make .= "DECIMAL({$field['MaximumLength']},{$post_point})";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Boolean") {
            $sql_make .= "CHAR(1)";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Date") {
            $sql_make .= "DATE default '0000-00-00' not null";
        }
        elseif ($field['DataType'] == "Time") {
            $sql_make .= "TIME default '00:00:00' not null";
        }
        else {
            $sql_make .= "VARCHAR(255)";
        }
        $sql_make .= " COMMENT '{$cleaned_comment}'";
        $sql_make .= ",\n";
        $sql_query .= $sql_make;
    }
    $sql_query .= "`Photos` TEXT COMMENT 'Photos Array', ";
    $sql_query .= "PRIMARY KEY(`{$field_prefix}{$key_field}`) )";
    return $sql_query;
}
private function get_previous_start_time()
{
    $filename = "previous_start_time_A.txt";
    // See if file exists
    if(file_exists($this->config['start_times_path'].$filename))
    {
        $time=time();
        $this->updates_log = fopen($this->config['start_times_path'].$filename, "r+");
        $this->previous_start_time = fgets($this->updates_log);
        $this->current_start_time = date("Y-m-d", $time) . 'T' . date("H:i:s", $time);
    } else {
        // Create file
        $this->updates_log = fopen($this->config['start_times_path'].$filename, "w+");
        fwrite($this->updates_log, "1980-01-01T00:00:00\n");
        $this->get_previous_start_time();
    }
    // fgets reads up to & includes the first newline, strip it
    return str_replace("\n", '', $this->previous_start_time);
}
private function set_previous_start_time()
{
    $file = $this->config['start_times_path'] . "previous_start_time_A.txt";
    $file_data = $this->current_start_time."\n";
    $file_data .= file_get_contents($file);
    file_put_contents($file, $file_data);
}
private function logging_start()
{
    $filename = "Log".date("m-d-y_h-i-s", time()).".txt";
    // See if file exists
    if(file_exists($this->config['logs_path'].$filename))
    {
        $this->log = fopen($this->config['logs_path'].$filename, "a");
    } else {
        // Create file
        $this->log = fopen($this->config['logs_path'].$filename, "w+");
    }
}
private function log_data($data)
{
    $write_data = "\nInfo Message: [".date("m/d/y - h:i:s", time())."]\n------------------------------------------------\n";
    $write_data .= $data."\n";
    $write_data .= "\n------------------------------------------------\n";
    fwrite($this->log, $write_data);
    if($this->config['to_screen'])
    {
        echo str_replace(array("\n"), array('<br />'), $write_data);
    }
}
private function log_error($error)
{
    $write_data = "\nError Message: [".date("m/d/y - h:i:s", time())."]\n------------------------------------------------\n";
    $write_data .= $error."\n";
    $write_data .= "\n------------------------------------------------\n";
    fwrite($this->log, $write_data);
    if($this->config['to_screen'])
    {
        echo str_replace(array("\n"), array('<br />'), $write_data);
    }
}
private function logging_end()
{
    $this->scriptend = date("m-d-y_h-i-s", time());
    $this->log_data("Closing log file.\n
                     Start Time: {$this->scriptstart}\n
                     End Time: {$this->scriptend}");
    fclose($this->log);
}
}
// Load the class
$retshelper = new RETSHELPER;
```

Sorry for the wall of code; I would shorten it down but I'm at a loss with what is still needed and what isn't. Once again, any help would or a point into the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: have you look into `set_time_limit(0);`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @cmorrissey I've got that set up in my PHP.ini file; but unfortunately the server host I have has a max limit of 5 minutes before it times out, regardless of what the time_limit is set to.